# Kendo Binary Reference could not be found in App_code view

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to `KendoUI`. I have included the binary reference in my project for `KendoUI`.

I am trying `'@using Kendo.Mvc.UI'` in a View inside `app_code`.

Visual Studio can't find reference.

It works fine outside app_code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the Build Action of the .cs file to **Content** instead of **Compile**

If you want to read more about the build actions [here](http://wingedpost.org/2015/09/various-build-actions-in-visual-studio/)

**Updated**

The following are some common build actions.

1. **None**: The file is not included in the project output group and is
   not    compiled in the build process. An example is a text file that
   contains documentation, such as a Readme file.
2. **Compile**: The file is
       compiled into the build output. This setting is used for code files.
3. **Content**: Allows you to retrieve a file (in same dir as assembly) as
   a    stream via Application.GetContentStream( uri ). For this method
   to       work, it needs a AssemblyAssociatedContentFile custom
   attribute which    VS graciously adds when you mark a file as
   “Content”
4. **Embedded       resource**: embeds the file in an exclusive
           assembly manifest resource.

Note: WPF have some additional build actions, but the above are the essential build actions and it will do the trick.